# ui-grid angularjs inside bootstrap nav-tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap 3 in angularjs as this

```
<tabset justified="true">
  <tab heading="TAB 1"></tab>
  <tab heading="TAB 2">
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions"></div></tab>
</tabset>
```

I get the grid as below

[image]

Why is that so?

If I take grid out of the tab, it works well.

Also on resize the window, it renders well.
Why not on page load?

How do i overcome it?
It would be better if I get some standard solution instead of some window resize event handling.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29024437/cant-get-ui-grid-to-work-in-bootbox-custom-dialog ..  Some bootstrap features cause an animation delay, dirty hack is to use a timeOut to call the grid rendering:  $timeout( function() {$scope.gridApi.core.handleWindowResize();}, 1000);

Answer (score 0):

As of bootstrap 3 and ui-grid 3.1.x I would recommend using [css visibility solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/kp2ixPGywaXPurBBHM3x?p=preview).

This will help with other issues that crop up even IE 11+ and on touch devices.

The solution is around using `visibility: hidden` css and using absolute positioning. It lets the grid objects to be created, initialized and ready to render correctly even if the user does not see them.